# How to solve an algebraic exponential equation in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am working on calculating money-weighted rate of return for my portfolio. I have to solve the following equation for r:

```
$298,082 = ($250,000 * (1 + r)) + ($25,000 * (1 + r)^((365 - 258)/365)))
```

...which simplifies to:

```
$298,082 = ($250,000 * (1 + r)) + ($25,000 * (1 + r)^(0.293150685))
```

Is there an easy way to do this in Excel? I am using Excel 2016.

Comment: Have you looked at the built-in financial functions?  They're pretty extensive and it might be as simple as plugging parameters into a canned function.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using Goal Seek. Set up the worksheet first: put a value for r in a cell (e.g. put 1 in C4), and put the formula in another, referencing the cell containing the value of R: `=(250000*(1+C4))+(25000*(1+C4)^(365-258)/365)` (let's assume that that's in D4).

Now on the Data Tab, in the Forecast group, select What-if Analysis and in the drop-down list that shows select Goal Seek. That brings up this dialog box:

[image: Screen shot]

I want to set cell D4 to the value 298082, by changing cell C4. Click OK and will change C4 untill it gets close to the required value. In this case, it set C4 (r) to 0.059459 which gave the formula the exact value required.

Comment: Ugh, I was hoping for something a little easier to use, especially if I have to solve multiple equations. Why can't we just use something on the formula bar, like a built-in function, for this? I guess Excel's not the best tool to use for maths?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the [XIRR](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Xirr-Function.html) function which "returns the Internal Rate of Return for a supplied series of cash flows"

Syntax is '=XIRR( values, dates, [guess] )'

And an example below.  Note all your investments you be negative with your final value being positive.  Also dates are all relative so if you put in dates 0, 258 and 365 this would work fine.

Using that I get 8.98% for your return.

[image]